# FullCalendar in cakePHP 3.0 not displaying events on calendar

Tags: cakephp, fullcalendar

I am upgrading to cakePHP 3.0 and have almost all of the functionality of the FullCalendar plugin working except I can't get any events to populate on the calendar. I am not getting anymore error messages, which makes this difficult to solve. My controller method looks like this:

```
public function feed($id=null)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['get']);
    $this->layout = "ajax";
    $vars = $this->params['url'];
    $conditions = ['conditions' => ['UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) >=' => $vars['start'], 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) <=' => $vars['end']]];
    $events = $this->Events->find('all', $conditions);
    foreach($events as $event) {
        if($event->all_day == 1) {
            $allday = true;
            $end = $event->start;
        } else {
            $allday = false;
            $end = $event->end;
        }
        $data[] = array(
                'id' => $event->id,
                'title'=>$event->title,
                'start'=>$event->start,
                'end' => $end,
                'allDay' => $allday,
                'url' => Router::url('/') . 'full_calendar/events/view/'.$event->id,
                'details' => $event->details,
                'className' => $event->event_type->color
        );
    }
    $this->set("json", json_encode($data));
}
```

My View is :

```
<?php
/*
 * View/FullCalendar/index.ctp
 * CakePHP Full Calendar Plugin
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Silas Montgomery
 * http://silasmontgomery.com
 *
 * Licensed under MIT
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */
?>
<div class="page-width">
    <script type="text/javascript">plgFcRoot = "/<site name>/" + "full_calendar"; console.log(plgFcRoot);</script>
    <?php
    echo $this->Html->script(['/full_calendar/js/jquery-1.5.min', '/full_calendar/js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min', '/full_calendar/js/fullcalendar.min', '/full_calendar/js/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min', '/full_calendar/js/ready']);
    echo $this->Html->css('/full_calendar/css/fullcalendar');
    ?>
    <div class="Calendar index">
        <div id="calendar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <ul>
            <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('New Event', true), ['controller' => 'events', 'action' => 'add']) ?></li>
            <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Manage Events', true), ['controller' => 'events']) ?></li>
            <li><?= $this->Html->link(__('Manage Events Types', true), ['controller' => 'event_types']) ?></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My ready.js is:

```
/*
 * webroot/js/ready.js 
 * CakePHP Full Calendar Plugin
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010 Silas Montgomery
 * http://silasmontgomery.com
 *
 * Licensed under MIT
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function() {

// page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    header: {
        left:   'title',
        center: '',
        right:  'today agendaDay,agendaWeek,month prev,next'
    },
    defaultView: 'month',
    firstHour: 8,
    weekMode: 'variable',
    aspectRatio: 2,
    editable: false,
    events: plgFcRoot + "/events/feed",
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
        element.qtip({
            content: event.details,
            position: { 
                target: 'mouse',
                adjust: {
                    x: 10,
                    y: -5
                }
            },
            style: {
                name: 'light',
                tip: 'leftTop'
            }
        });
    },
    eventDragStart: function(event) {
        $(this).qtip("destroy");
    },
    eventDrop: function(event) {
        var startdate = new Date(event.start);
        var startyear = startdate.getFullYear();
        var startday = startdate.getDate();
        var startmonth = startdate.getMonth()+1;
        var starthour = startdate.getHours();
        var startminute = startdate.getMinutes();
        var enddate = new Date(event.end);
        var endyear = enddate.getFullYear();
        var endday = enddate.getDate();
        var endmonth = enddate.getMonth()+1;
        var endhour = enddate.getHours();
        var endminute = enddate.getMinutes();
        if(event.allDay == true) {
            var allday = 1;
        } else {
            var allday = 0;
        }
        var url = plgFcRoot + "/events/update?id="+event.id+"&start="+startyear+"-"+startmonth+"-"+startday+" "+starthour+":"+startminute+":00&end="+endyear+"-"+endmonth+"-"+endday+" "+endhour+":"+endminute+":00&allday="+allday;
        $.post(url, function(data){});
    },
    eventResizeStart: function(event) {
        $(this).qtip("destroy");
    },
    eventResize: function(event) {
        var startdate = new Date(event.start);
        var startyear = startdate.getFullYear();
        var startday = startdate.getDate();
        var startmonth = startdate.getMonth()+1;
        var starthour = startdate.getHours();
        var startminute = startdate.getMinutes();
        var enddate = new Date(event.end);
        var endyear = enddate.getFullYear();
        var endday = enddate.getDate();
        var endmonth = enddate.getMonth()+1;
        var endhour = enddate.getHours();
        var endminute = enddate.getMinutes();
        var url = plgFcRoot + "/events/update?id="+event.id+"&start="+startyear+"-"+startmonth+"-"+startday+" "+starthour+":"+startminute+":00&end="+endyear+"-"+endmonth+"-"+endday+" "+endhour+":"+endminute+":00";
        $.post(url, function(data){});
    }
})

});
```

Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.
Sometimes I get this error in the console, but not every time:
GET http://localhost//full_calendar/events/feed?start=1433052000&end=1436076000&_=1433266131989 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved my issue. I used a process of elimination and found that the conditions array that I had was set up incorrectly for cakePHP 3.0, so it was a cake issue. Instead of

CakePHP 2.x Syntax

```
$conditions = array('conditions' => array('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) >=' => $vars['start'], 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) <=' => $vars['end']));
$events = $this->Event->find('all', $conditions);
```

it is:

CakePHP 3.x Syntax

```
$conditions = ['UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) >=' => $vars['start'], 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) <=' => $vars['end']];
$events = $this->Events->find('all', $conditions)->contain(['EventTypes']);
```

There isn't a conditions setting in the array, you just set the conditions which I got from this example in the cakePHP documentation:

```
$this->loadModel('Articles');
$recentArticles = $this->Articles->find('all', [
    'limit' => 5,
    'order' => 'Articles.created DESC'
]);
```

Comment: Is there any chance your could summarise your setup to get this working please, i.e. what files from the download you put where and so on? I am struggling to even get it set up.

Comment: It was quite the process to figure out how to get this to work on cakephp 3.x. Let me run some tests to see how I can simplify the process and I will let you know.

Comment: I added a 3.x branch to silas' original repository. Use this link and follow installation steps in readme file to get it going in cakephp 3.x. Let me know if you have problems. https://github.com/curtisblack2004/CakePHP-Full-Calendar-Plugin/tree/3.x

Comment: Wow. I really appreciate the time and effort you put into this. I have quickly set it up at my desk now. All working fine, just the drag and drop feature that's not, but you do state that needs fixing. Thank you!

Comment: I'm finally getting around to using your branch of Silas' repository. All fine until I implement auth, which results in a 500 error upon loading the full-calendar index page. Everything loads but it looks like the json fails so no events are displayed. I just hit this now so will try to sort it myself. If you have a quick silver bullet, please let me know.

Comment: I would need to know a lot more information to figure out why it's not working for you. How did you implement auth?, did you get it working correctly before implementing auth?, etc. You might just need to unlock the feed method in your beforeFilter in the events controller. Try adding $this->Auth->allow(['feed']); in that controller in the beforeFilter() method.

Comment: Auth is implemented as per the blog tutorial. Nothing special. If I turn off auth it works fine. I was messing with allow yesterday but had no idea I could allow feed as an action. I won't be able to test until later today but have a feeling what you suggest will work. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I added this:

    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
            parent::beforeFilter();
            $this->Auth->allow(['feed']);
    }

In the events controller, as well as use Cake\Event\Event;

It makes no difference yet, but I feel like I'm getting closer. The error I get is:

    {
    "message": "Template file \u0022Events\/feed.ctp\u0022 is missing.",
    "url": "\/events\/feed.json?start=2016-08-28\u0026amp;end=2016-10-02\u0026amp;_=1474447852139",
    "code": 500,

.....etc

Calendar loads sans events. The changes made so far have made no difference.

Comment: Fixed. Was an issue with the AppController - it needed public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
            in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
        ) {
            $this->set('_serialize', true);
        }
    }

Comment: @pmelon Nice! glad you figured that out. I have that same function in my AppController.